# What are the benefits to use const pointers or const data?

Tags: c, security, pointers, constants, buffer-overflow

How can a non const pointer (that allows to access in nearby memory) or a non const data be exploited?

I studied that a non const pointer can be exploited to access in nearby memory of computer.

But my question is: how?

I mean, **if I have started my compiled program, how can an attacker exploit it if it is already compiled and running?**

Is this a dangerous vulnerability? Or it isn't so important?

Comment: >You can always cast a pointer to remove the const if you want.

But how if the program  is already compiled and running with const pointers/data?

Comment: C isn't an interpreted language, it's a compiled language.  The main issue you could run into is if the compiler allocates some storage to constant memory, or if it assumes something hasn't changed when in fact you've bypassed the type system and changed it.  Again, none of these are "exploits".  The worst you could do would be essentially equivalent to dereferening a bad pointer value.  You could crash your program, or get unexpected results, but just because you can have a bug in your code doesn't mean you're suddenly going to be able to exploit it somehow.

Comment: @TomKarzes: `const` should not be used or relied on as documentation that a function does not change the pointed-to data because C does not require that and because there are circumstances where a function must remove `const` internally.

Comment: @TomKarzes: No, you do not have to make an assumption. Authors can document their code, and users can read the documentation.

Comment: @TomKarzes: (a) The fact that the man page is a certain way does not mean that it must be that way. If it is missing information, that is a defect of its authorship, not proof of a logical necessity. File a defect report. (b) The documentation is understood to tell you what a function does, and omission of some act means it does not perform that act. For example, if the documentation for a function does not say it sets `errno`, then it should not set `errno`. While this might be classified as an assumption, I would characterize it as a convention in documentation rather than an assumption.

Comment: @TomKarzes: (c) Further, `const` **cannot** serve as documentation that the pointed-to memory is not modified since, as stated before, in some circumstances, it is necessary to use `const` but remove it by a cast.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, so you're saying that if an argument is modified, then the documentation must explicitly say it's modified.  Alright, I'll buy that.  But regarding `const`, you're saying that you should basically ignore it in the documentation, and instead see if it says it's modified.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It makes me wonder how useful `const` really is.  The basic idea is good enough, but there are all kinds of exceptions to it, and cases where the compiler complains where you wouldn't expect it to.  If you make aggressive use of it, it seems like you end up having to use casts to circumvent it.

Answer (score 0):

**Constant Pointer**
A constant pointer in C cannot change the address of the variable to which it is pointing, i.e., the address will remain constant. Therefore, we can say that if a constant pointer is pointing to some variable, then it cannot point to any other variable.

**Constant Data**

1. Code Maintenance
   *Say I have a need to use the speed of light for calculations throughout my project. The speed of light is not going to change so there is no need for a variable. I could simply copy and paste 300,000,000 (obviously without the commas) anytime I need the speed of light (in meters per second). This will work fine for now but down the road my calculations may require more precision so if I want to change 300,000,000 to 299,792,458 it will be a fairly painful process if I used this value a lot in my code. If I use a const I can use this the name of this const throughout the code so if I need to change its value I can just change it once at the beginning of the code.*
2. Memory
   *This isn’t usually relevant given the computing power of modern devices but for software on embedded devices there may not be the RAM space for variables and by using a const its value is put into the program when the code is compiled. This allows storage space (on the HDD/SSD) to be used instead of the RAM.*
3. Accidental Changes
   *If you need a value to stay constant use a const so that you don’t accidentally change its value later on because you forget that you need its value to remain the same. Think of it this way, if its value is not going to change throughout the code why wouldn’t you use a const.*

Answer (score -2):

Pointers in C are the most dangerous entity that has potential exploit your RAM. If you somehow know the base address of the pointer where it is pointing, use that address to move forward or backward in the memory and do whatever you want since in C there is no exception handling of OutofBoundException.

For that, you need to have a good understanding of pointers.

Comment: this question does not answer anything.